# How can I capture what is happening when a that are being removed during a

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon SO!
I am still new to powershell and I'm looking for a way to record what happens after 
I invoke Command as for example on Line 51.

Can I print the device logging into that directory?

On Line 52 after `DEL *.*` happens is it possible to print what is being deleted to file?

i.e.

```
51 Invoke-Command -device $ipaddress -command 'cd \firmware'| Out-File $LogFileName -Append;
52 Invoke-Command -device $ipaddress -command 'DEL *.*'| Out-File $LogFileName -Append;

Stop Transcript

}`
```

I've tried using Start-Transcript -path $LogFileName -append // Stop Transcript but this doesnt print what is happen when every command is invoked.

Comment: It is not clear what you expect to see. There is no `-device` parameter for `Invoke-Command`. What does appear in the transcript?

Comment: Thank you lit for the feedback, i was trying to capture whatever action is happening at the line.

Comment: Your pseudo code portrays that you invoke the command "CD" then treat down the session. Then invoke a new command "del" this is extremely bad practice. Use a script block to invoke the multiple commands together. But then again it's pseudo code. `invoke-command -computername $device -scriptblock {CD \firmware; del *.* -verbose} -sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofule)` is the line more or less.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCotterman for the Feedback.

Comment: I meant close down. Not "treat down" phone autocorrect. But yeah. Your second session would del *.* Of system32 most likely. Lol. Just like to put in help where I can because if something goes wrong it's best to know why

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 2nd question:

> On Line 52 after DEL *.* happens is it possible to print what is being
>   deleted to file?

`Remove-Item` (aka `DEL`) has a switch `-Verbose` that will output the list of files deleted. The rub is that it outputs the list to the "verbose" stream. Powershell can generate output on one of many streams in addition to the traditional output stream and error stream. One of those is the verbose stream. Unfortunately, only the output stream passed down the pipeline, the other streams just get output to the console. Fortunately, you can re-direct these other streams to the out stream by using the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) `>&`. On the left side of the operator, you include the # of the stream you want to redirect from, and on the right side, what you want to redirect to. For your example, you want to redirect from the verbose stream (4) to the output stream (1):

```
4>&1
```

So the command would look like this:

```
Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {del *.* -Verbose 4>&1} | Out-File $LogFileName -Append
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, zdan.  I'll test this out.  i greatly appreciate the assistance